# Remove slide number and footer on quarto title slide

Tags: r, markdown, quarto

Is it possible to remove `slide-number` and `footer` elements from the title slide in Quarto?

```
---
title: "My prez"
format:
  revealjs:
    slide-number: c
    footer: "Confidential"
---
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Revealjs API methods. So write the necessary Js code (To capture the event of slide being ready and slide changed and if the current slide is title slide, change the display of footer and slide number to `none`) in a html file and then attach that file to qmd file using `include-after-body`.

```
---
title: "My prez"
format:
  revealjs:
    slide-number: c
    footer: "Confidential"
    include-after-body: clean_title_page.html
---

## Slide A


## Slide B
```

**clean_title_page.html**

```
<style>
  .hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>


<script>
  function remove() {
    let footer = document.querySelector('div.footer');
    let slideNo = document.querySelector('div.slide-number');
    slideNo.classList.add('hide');
    footer.classList.add('hide');
  
    Reveal.on('slidechanged', event => {  
      if(Reveal.isFirstSlide()) {
        slideNo.classList.add('hide');
        footer.classList.add('hide');
      } else {
        slideNo.classList.remove('hide');
        footer.classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
  }
  
  window.onload = remove();
</script>
```

---

[image: hide footer and slide number]

---